# How HttpServletRequest works

Tags: servlets

i'm trying to understand how HttpServletRequest works:

in a demo application I have this code in a .class file:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String parameter = req.getHeader("PARAMETER");
```

is this a JSF implementation? Does it read a parameter from the session right?

How can I retrieve the same parameter without using JSF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this snippet is part of a JSF application.

No it doesn't read a parameter from the session, since it calls getHeader() on a HttpServletRequest object. So it reads a request header (as [the javadoc of `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) explains).

To retrieve the same header in a simple servlet-based application, you would use the `HttpServletRequest` argument passed to every servlet method:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String header = request.getHeader("PARAMETER");
    ...
}
```

It looks like you're not familiar at all with servlets. Read an introductory tutorial to grasp the basics before dving into code.

Comment: ok your answer is valid in a Java Servlet, but what if i'm in a java bean class? I don't have that request and response object right? Thank you so much, really

Comment: Then pass it as argument. It's also possible to save it in a ThreadLocal variable, but I wouldn't do it. But the best thing to do is to design your app so that only the servlet deals with the request: it builds regular, type-safe Java objects from what the request contains, and passes those objects to other layers of the app. Modern MVC frameworks do that for you, so that you don't even have to deal with the request anywhere.